# Version Checker with Jsoup not working anymore

Tags: android, google-play, jsoup, version, android-studio-3.0

I have an application live on Play store for almost a year. I am using below code to check current version and show user popup to update if new version available.

```
private boolean checkVersionNumber() {
            boolean isCurrentVersion = true;
            DebugLog.d(TAG + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getPackageName());

            VersionChecker versionChecker = new VersionChecker();

            try {
                String latestVersion = versionChecker.execute().get();
                PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
                String currentVersion = pInfo.versionName;

                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(latestVersion) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(currentVersion)) {
                    DebugLog.d(TAG + "checkVersionNumber: VERSIONS NOT EMPTY");
                    if (latestVersion.equalsIgnoreCase(currentVersion)) {
                        DebugLog.d(TAG + "checkVersionNumber: IS THE CURRENT VERSION");
                        isCurrentVersion = true;
                    } else {
                        DebugLog.d(TAG + "checkVersionNumber: IS THE CURRENT VERSION");
                        isCurrentVersion = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    DebugLog.d(TAG + "checkVersionNumber: VERSIONS WERE EMPTY");
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return isCurrentVersion;

        }
```

Below is code for **VersionChecker**

```
public class VersionChecker extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        String newVersion;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                newVersion = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getPackageName())
                        .timeout(30000)
                        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                        .referrer("http://www.google.com").get()
                        .select("div[itemprop=softwareVersion]").first()
                        .ownText();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return newVersion;
        }
    }
```

It was working fine so far. But for past one month, all users are getting below crash.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.jsoup.nodes.Element.ownText()' on a null object reference
                                                                             at com.myapp.activity.SplashActivity$VersionChecker.doInBackground(SplashActivity.java:190)
                                                                             at com.myapp.activity.SplashActivity$VersionChecker.doInBackground(SplashActivity.java:176)
                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

I am not sure what is wrong. Does anyone know if this api is working or not anymore..???

Comment: The fact that you are getting a null reference exception means that there is no element like `div[itemprop=softwareVersion]` on the page; maybe the html has changed since you originally built it. What does the html look like when you get the url?

Comment: @Justin How can I get the proper HTML ..??

Comment: The `Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getPackageName()).timeout(30000).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6").referrer("http://www.google.com").get()` would be the html you are parsing. What does that look like?

Answer (score 1):

Parsing the Play store for the current version is a really bad idea. The Play store can change it's HTML at any time (as you have found out). It also treats users who have a legitimate reason for staying on an old version (eg they are travelling and have very expensive internet) for a little while badly.

A much better idea would be to use something like [Firebase remote config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/) to configure the minimum acceptable version of your app. Update this to the latest version some time (maybe a week or two) after you have released the app update. That way:

- you have complete control over the process
- Play Store HTML changes won't cause crashes
- you give users a chance to control when they upgrade to when is convenient to them